# How can I limit the scope of a variable to a single file?

Tags: php

I have several functions which share common variables. But I don't want to keep passing these variables between all the functions, because that means all functions will have a lot of parameters and I find that hard to read.

So I want to define 'global' variables only for these functions, something like so:

```
$varA;
$varB;
$varC;

function funcA() {
    ..
}

function funcB() {
    ..
}

function funcC() {
    ..
}
```

As opposed to the ugly way of funcA declaring the variables and functions passing them around between them (resulting in many parameters for each function).

However I want the variables to not be global to all files in the program. Only accessible in this file.

What is the best or most common way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really want to build objects, but only want to have a private scope, you could use static class:

```
<?php

class Example {
    private static $shared_variable;

    /* disable the constructor to create a static class */
    private function __construct() {}

    static function funcA() {
        self::$shared_variable = 'AVAILABLE HERE';
    }

    static function funcB() {
        echo self::$shared_variable;
    }
}

Example::funcA();
Example::funcB();

// echo Example::$shared_variable; // but not here
```

I added the private delaration of constructor to prevent the object creation (thus declaring the class static).

Comment: Personally I'd avoid static variables and methods if possible.

Comment: I agree. But when one wants to create a shared scope I think it's a reasonable option. What do you propose? Creating only one object of the non-static, maybe even singleton?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class and refactor the functions to methods and the variables to parameters:

```
Class newClass
{
    private $varA;
    private $varB;
    private $varC;

    public function funcA()
    {
        $varB = $this->varB;
    }

    public function funcB()
    {
        $varC = $this->varC;
    }

    public function funcC()
    {
        $varA = $this->varA;
    }

}
```

This way you will have full access to all the set parameters in all your subsequent methods. You can write a setter or create a constructor to add a value to your parameters:

```
Class newClass
{
    public function __construct($varA, $varB, $varC)
    {
        $this->varA = $varA;
        $this->varB = $varB;
        $this->varC = $varC;
    }
}
```

This is how I would handle the local scope. Good luck!

Comment: than he will have different variables per instance (if one instance changes one variable) or has to hand over the instance

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of encapsulating variables and functions which depends on these variables is by using a class.

```
class MyClass
{
    private $varA;
    private $varB;
    private $varC;

   public function __construct($varA, $varB, $varC)
   {
       $this->varA = $varA;
       $this->varB = $varB;
       $this->varC = $varC;
   }

    public function funcA()
    {
        $localVarB = $this->varB;
    }

    public function funcB()
    {
        $localVarC = $this->varC;
    }

    public function funcC()
    {
        $localVarA = $this->varA;
    }    
}
```

To use this class you must first create an instance of it:

```
$classInstance = new MyClass("varA", "varB", "value");
$classInstance->funcA();
$classInstance->funcB();
...
```

More information about classes in php can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php

Comment: than he will have different variables per instance (if one instance changes one variable) or has to hand over the instance

Comment: That's the intention. You do all work on an object which changes its state and then retrieve the values. In my example only one instance is created so there are no other instances which can have a different state.